# how to change content of newsletter email - Magento

Tags: php, magento, newsletter

I want to change the content of thank you email sent to a user when he is subscribed to newsletter in magento.

Subscription form is in  `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml` :

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">       
 </form>
```

getFormActionUrl function I found in `/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Block/Subscribe.php` :

```
 public function getFormActionUrl()
   {
      return $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', array('_secure' => true));
   }
```

I am new to magento, getUrl function is defined in many files, can any one point me to the file directly which have thank you for newsletter subscribing email message.

Comment: mahendra ,what you want???

Comment: getUrl is probably only defined in one place. Try searching the code for "function getUrl".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mahendra,If you want to change the only template please to

```
app>locale>en_US(your language)>template>email>newsletter_subscr_success.html
```

Comment: mahendra .Please change the title of question-"Where we found the newsletter subscription success  email template in magento"

Comment: Or how to change content of newsletter email template - Magento